# TCP client to server corrupts data

Tags: c#, tcp

This is very weird.

When I send data to a TCP server, with a TCP client. It corrupts the data, for some extremely odd, and quite annoying reason.

Here is the server code:

```
TcpListener lis = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9380); // it needs to be 9380, crucial
lis.Start();
Socket sk = lis.AcceptSocket();
byte[] pd = new byte[sk.ReceiveBufferSize];
sk.Receive(pd);

// cd is the current directory, filename is the file, ex picture.png, 
// that was previously sent to the server with UDP.
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(cd, filename), pd);
```

Here is the client code:

```
// disregard "filename" var, it was previously assigned in earlier code
byte[] p = File.ReadAllBytes(filename) 
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(getIP()), 9380);
Stream st = client.GetStream();
st.Write(p, 0, p.Length);
```

What happens is data loss. Extreme, sometimes I would upload a 5KB file, but when the server receives and writes the file I send it, it would turn out crazy like 2 bytes. Or it would be 8KB instead! Applications send through this won't even run, pictures show errors, ect.

I would like to note, however, with this, client -> server fails, on the other hand, server -> client works. Strange.

Btw, in case you are interested this is for sending files... Also, using .NET 4.5. Also, my network is extremely reliable.

Comment: It could be an endian issue. Also it would be better to send the file in chunks.

Comment: Why downvotes? Because you can't figure it out?

Comment: I tried in small chunks too, of 2048 bytes. It still corrupts. Help? @Bauss

Comment: Can you explain what corrupts about it? Lost bytes, invalid data? Did you try to reverse the bytes received, like I said with "endian issue".

Comment: :( I think the other guy deleted his answer because I am annoying and and idiot. I feel sad now. At least I think I know what needs to happen.

Comment: I thought about it some more, and the int Receive returns that the other guy was talking about is the number of bytes, I think I must compare *that*

Comment: So do I have to keep asking the client to send the data, until it gets it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you have some misconceptions about TCP.
I can see you are setting up a server with a receive buffer of x bytes. 
Firstly have you checked to see how many bytes that is? I suspect it is very small something like 1024 or something.
When writing data over TCP the data is split into frames. Each time you receive you will get some of the data sent and it will tell you how much of the data has been [received](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx) . As I can see from your use case you do not know the size of the data to receive so you will have to build up a protocol between your client and server to communicate this. The simplest of such would be to write a 4 byte integer specifying the size of the data to be received. 
The communication would go like this.

### Client:

1. Write 4 bytes (file size)
2. Write Data bytes

### Server:

1. Read 4 bytes (file size)
2. While we have yet to receive file size read
   the stream and push bytes into memory/file stream